# Django - Avoid writing duplicate code

Tags: python, django

I want to create 2 web pages which use the same code but I don't want to copy/paste the code in 2 places. I'm sure I don't need to have the same code in 2 different places to use it on multiple pages. Can someone suggest a way to avoid creating duplicate code?

If required, I can provide some sample code which I've already written.

Comment: It really depends what the code does. Is it business logic, presentation logic, routing logic, view setup...?

Comment: Create a template and reuse it??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For generating HTML on the frontend, you can use templates to create static content which can be used across multiple pages on your site.

For more information on how to use django templates, see: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/templates/

As for the backend, you'll need to write your code as re-usable as possible and then import/reuse as much as you can. Pylint has a check for similar/duplicate code:

For more information on Pylint similarities-checker, see: https://docs.pylint.org/features.html#similarities-checker

Answer (score 1):

Use this built-in django template tag for that:

```
{% include "subtemplate.html" %}
```